# Are there two different types of "tongues" spoken about in the NT?

Tags: 1-corinthians, acts, historical-interpretation, authorial-intent, pneumatology

My question comes directly from 1 Cor 14: 2, 4:

> 2 For one who speaks in a tongue does not speak to men but to God; for
>   no one understands, but in his spirit he speaks mysteries.....4 One who speaks in a tongue edifies himself; but one who prophesies edifies the church. (NASB)

In Acts 2:4-11 tongues were heard and understood by many people of different nations there in Jerusalem. However, what Paul describes in 1 Corinthians sounds like they are not understood.

Is the phenomenon that Paul speaks of different from the kind of "tongues" in Acts 2?

Comment: That, my friend, was an excellent question. If you want to ask ask the question whether or not glossolalia is a human language, I would be happy to post an answer to that question as well. But that issue seems to fall outside the scope of this question. Kudos.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to BH-SE.  This forum is somewhat unique.  I see your interest is in sound doctrine, mine too!  While hopefully what you contribute and find here will be sound, the purpose of the forum is to explore the meaning of Scripture by observing language, text, context, etc.  The forum does not deal with how the text applies today. Questions begin with a particular passage, avoid doctrinal premise and do not seek application. Answers begin with the text, show each logical step toward an answer to the question, support assertions with credible sources, and stop short of application. :)

Comment: I edited your post in hopes to avoid its being closed.   Those who edit are usually trying to help you; however, you are free to roll back any edit of your posts.  Please take a moment to review the reasons I gave for the edit.  That and my above post should provide you with some basic principles to edit your own post and make it appropriate for this forum.  I look forward to seeing your future posts.

Comment: That was a well written article I seen hermeneutics. And I thought you would reply with tongues are not for today and other foolishness. I couldn't of answered it better myself good to know there are likeminded believers out there.

Answer (score 4):

> Are their two different types of “tongues” spoke about in the NT?

I believe it would be a misnomer to say that there are two different “types” of tongues. However, there are two separate and distinct “operations” of tongues.

***The Operation of Tongues***

The gift of speaking in tongues is seen to operate in two distinct ways: personal and corporate. Though these two operations are separate and distinct, they may often overlap in varying degrees. I will say more about this, later.

Both of these operations are made manifest through the natural vehicle of speech. This may seem a bit of an overstatement, but many people who have received the Holy Spirit baptism are not SPEAKING in tongues. People who have received the Holy Spirit baptism, but do not speak in tongues, sometimes get the idea that the Holy Spirit will come upon them and “cause” them to speak out in tongues. This idea could not be further from the truth.

I can still recall how I used to sit with my mouth opened, eagerly waiting for the Holy Spirit to come upon me and USE me to speak in tongues. Oh, I was very clever about it. I would sit with my hand over my mouth (so no one would see how foolish I looked) and wait for the MIRACLE OF GOD to speak the heavenly language through this humble and willing vessel. I expected him to move my lips and mouth and MAKE the utterance come out. I suppose I am the only person in the entire history of Christian humanity who has ever pulled that stunt. Many times I have helped people to realize their error in this area by using two illustrations which I will share with you now. First, I have the person read Acts 2:4.

> And they were all filled with the Holy Ghost, and began to speak with other tongues, as the Spirit gave them utterance.

Once they have read this verse of scripture, I ask them to tell me who was doing the speaking. At this point I get nearly an even split, with one half opting for the people, and the other half for the Holy Spirit. I have those who choose the Holy Spirit reread the verse, pointing out that THEY were filled with the HOLY GHOST AND BEGAN TO SPEAK. Those who were filled with the Holy Ghost are the ones who spoke in tongues, but only as the Holy Spirit who gave them utterance.

To further press the point, I run through a short dramatization with the individual as follows. I have the person be himself, while I act the part of the Holy Spirit. Using a well know nursery rhyme such as "Mary Had a Little Lamb," I tell the person to repeat after me, and then I recite the rhyme. When we have completed the exercise, I ask the person, “Who was doing the speaking just now?” The reply is always that they were doing the speaking, of course. The next question is, “Where did you get the words to speak?” They respond that the words came from me, the pseudo Holy Spirit.

This is precisely how speaking in tongues works, with one variation. The Holy Spirit puts the utterance in our spirits, not in our heads. When the Holy Spirit places the utterance in our spirit we speak out that utterance in natural fashion by using our tongue, larynx, diaphragm, and lips. This becomes the foundation of the second dramatization. I tell the person to recite the nursery rhyme again, but this time they are not to use their tongue, larynx, diaphragm, or lips when they speak out. The result is always the same, the most beautiful silence anyone could ask for.

I then explain that therein lies the reason for their failure to speak in tongues - they are not speaking at all. They have not been going through the motions of generating the sounds of speech which always results in SILENCE. When they do not speak in tongues automatically, they assume they are the one who does not get to speak in tongues as they have been given to understand by pastor Don T. Rocktheboat from 1 Corinthians 12:29-30 (more on this later).

It simply cannot be overstated: the supernatural gift of speaking in tongues is realized through the natural gift of speech.

***I. Personal Operation***

**A.** The first purpose of this operation of tongues is to be a **sign**. Mark 16:17 says,

> And these signs shall follow them that believe; In my name shall they cast out devils; they shall speak with new tongues;

You should have no trouble seeing that the first purpose for speaking in tongues is a sign of being a believer in Yeshua Messiah. But tongues is even more of a sign than that.
The early church recognized speaking in tongues as the evidence of the Holy Spirit baptism (Acts 2:16-18; 10:46; 19:6), and they did so with good reason.

Only those who had received the Holy Spirit baptism spoke in tongues. Indeed, speaking in other tongues was the initial evidence of the outpouring of the Holy Spirit on the day of Pentecost.

**B)** The second purpose for personal prayer and edification tongues is for **edification**. Jude 20 tells us:

> But ye, beloved, building up yourselves on your most holy faith, praying in the Holy Ghost.

Here we see those who speak in tongues are built up or edified in the area of their faith by speaking in tongues. 1 Corinthians 14:4 is even more directly stated.

> He that speaketh in an unknown tongue edifieth himself; but he that
>   prophesieth edifieth the church.

Speaking in tongues edifies the speaker, but not the hearer. Prophecy edifies both the speaker and the hearer. You will recall Romans 10:17

> So then faith cometh by hearing, and hearing by the word of God.

Since faith comes by hearing the word of God, it would stand to reason that speaking in tongues would have to incorporate the word of God if it was going to increase us in the area of our faith. Tongues do exactly that. Tongues are used to speak the perfect will of God directly to God. I am sure we can all agree that God’s word is his will.

> Romans 8:26-27 Likewise the Spirit also helpeth our infirmities: for
>    we know not what we should pray for as we ought: but the Spirit itself
>    maketh intercession for us with groanings which cannot be uttered. And
>    he that searcheth the hearts knoweth what is the mind of the Spirit,
>    because he maketh intercession for the saints according to the will of
>    God.
>
> 1 Corinthians 14:2, 4 For he that speaketh in an unknown tongue
>    speaketh not unto men, but unto God: for no man understandeth him;
>    howbeit in the spirit he speaketh mysteries. He that speaketh in an
>    unknown tongue edifieth himself; but he that prophesieth edifieth the
>    church.

The Holy Spirit gives us the perfect will of God.

In these two passages we see that the Holy Spirit, in giving us the utterance to speak out in tongues, gives us the perfect will of God concerning the situation for which we are praying.

We also see that speaking in tongues is not to be understood by men, as it is an utterance directly to God (speaketh not unto men, but unto God).

**C)** The third purpose is to speak creative mysteries to God as we pray in tongues (1 Corinthians 14:2). First we create the result in the spiritual realm, then we pray in the understanding so the result can become a reality in the physical realm. The book of Job gives us insight into this dual expression of tongues.

> Job 11:6 And that he would shew thee the secrets of wisdom, that they are double to that which is!

The reason God tells us to pray for the understanding of our utterances in other tongues is of far greater importance than just “knowing” what we have spoken. When we confess something in the spiritual language, it becomes a reality in the spiritual realm. But you cannot cut your cake with a spiritual knife.

Once we have used the power of speaking in tongues to create what we need, we must (or someone else must) speak it out in the natural world so God can make it a physical reality. When we first speak out in tongues to create what we need or want, those things belong to God.

> The secret things belong unto the LORD our God: but those things which are revealed belong unto us and to our children for ever, that we may
>   do all the words of this law. Deuteronomy 29:29

When God gives us the interpretation, we speak out in the understanding so God can give that creation to us in the physical, natural realm, where we can use it to glorify him.

> 1 Corinthians 2:7 But we speak the wisdom of God in a mystery, even
>   the hidden wisdom, which God ordained before the world unto our glory:
>
> Isaiah 45:3 And I will give thee the treasures of darkness, and hidden
>   riches of secret places, that thou mayest know that I, the LORD, which
>   call thee by thy name, am the God of Israel.

That which you created will destroy the works of the devil!

The final purpose for personal prayer and edification tongues is **intercession**, as seen in Romans 8:26.

> Likewise the Spirit also helpeth our infirmities: for we know not what we should pray for as we ought: but the Spirit itself maketh intercession for us with groanings which cannot be uttered. And he that searcheth the hearts knoweth what is the mind of the Spirit, because he maketh intercession for the saints according to the will of God.

This is the best way to intercede for someone; to pray in tongues, thereby praying the perfect will of God for the person or situation we are making intercession.

We all have friends and loved ones whom we pray for on a regular basis. But what are we supposed to do when a situation arises in which we have no idea how we should pray or what we should pray for? Tongues is the answer!

Praying in tongues goes right to the heart of the issue by declaring the perfect will of God over the situation.

***Example:*** Tom and Pam are having problems in their marriage relationship. You have noticed the strain on their marriage, but you do not know why it is there. In short, you do not know what you should pray for as you ought. The best thing to do is to pray in tongues and allow the Holy Spirit to make intercession according to the perfect will of God. I know of nothing better to speak than the perfect will of God. Left to your own, you may pray that Bob be more understanding of Pam, or that Pam stop picking at Tom, when the real problem in the marriage is neither one of them is spending time in the word of God or prayer.

Personal prayer and edification tongues never requires interpretation because it is always personal. It is always directed to God alone! You are edified, and you did not intend for anyone else to join in on the prayer or the edification.

***II. Corporate Operation***

The second operation of tongues may be seen as the corporate operation, or the charismatic gift of speaking in tongues. The function of corporate tongues is the same as the function of personal tongues.

**A)** The first purpose of the charismatic gift of speaking in tongues is exactly the same as the first purpose of personal tongues, which is to be a **sign** to non believers who may happen to be present in the church service (1 Corinthians 14:22).

**B)** The second purpose for the corporate use of speaking in other tongues is **edification of the church**. Paul makes a distinction between personal prayer and edification-tongues and the charismatic gift of tongues in chapters 12-14 of 1 Corinthians. The charismatic gift of tongues is NOT for PERSONAL edification!

Apparently there was nearly as much turmoil over tongues in the early church as there is today. But the revelation Paul gives us is enough to quash any misunderstanding provided we listen to what Paul has told us.

It is both interesting and necessary to observe Paul’s use of the words *Body, Come Together, Church, and Members* in these three chapters of 1 Corinthians. The number of instances is as follows:

BODY = 15xs

COME TOGETHER = 2xs

CHURCH = 8xs

MEMBERS = 10xs

It becomes obvious that Paul is using the assembled church body as his context, and not people in their personal lives. It is necessary that you see this as being true in order for you to understand Paul’s discourse in these chapters. Paul stresses the fact that we (all together) are the (one) body of Christ in the following verses: 1 Corinthians 12:12-14, 17-20, 25-27; 14:19, 23, 26, 28, 33.

The key to understanding the purpose of the CORPORATE operation of tongues is found in 1 Corinthians 14:12.

> Even so ye, forasmuch as ye are zealous of spiritual gifts, seek that ye may excel to the edifying of the church.

You may recall the person who speaks in tongues edifies himself because no man understands him! When someone is going to speak in tongues in the assembled church body, the utterance must be accompanied by an interpretation so that the entire body may be edified and not just the speaker!

Personal tongues, therefore, edifies the speaker only, but the charismatic gift of speaking in tongues is for edification of the entire body. The only way to bring understanding to the entire body, when an utterance in tongues has been brought forth in the assembly, is to have the interpretation of that utterance brought forth as well. This has the net effect in the assembly of a word of prophecy (1 Corinthians 14:5).

Keeping in mind that 1 Corinthians 14:12 is the key to understanding the purpose of the corporate operation of tongues, let’s take a look at some of the verses of scripture in the fourteenth chapter of 1 Corinthians to see what does and what does not edify the entire church body.

> VERSE 2 For he that speaketh in an unknown tongue speaketh not unto men, but unto God: for no man understandeth him; howbeit in the spirit he speaketh mysteries.

This cannot edify the entire church body because no man understands JUST speaking in tongues. One must interpret if the entire body is to be edified.

> VERSE 3 But he that prophesieth speaketh unto men to edification, and exhortation, and comfort.

Edification is one of the primary functions of prophecy; therefore, it does edify the entire church body.

> VERSE 4 He that speaketh in an unknown tongue edifieth himself; but he that prophesieth edifieth the church.

It should be apparent that speaking in an unknown tongue only edifies the person who does the speaking, but it definitely does not edify the entire church body. Speaking a word of prophecy in the common language of the people, however, does serve to edify the entire church body.

> VERSE 5 I would that ye all spake with tongues but rather that ye prophesied: for greater is he that prophesieth than he that speaketh with tongues, except he interpret, that the church may receive edifying.

Speaking in tongues and having that utterance interpreted is the same as a word of prophecy because everyone is edified.

> VERSE 13 Wherefore let him that speaketh in an unknown tongue pray that he may interpret.

As we just saw, tongues, when accompanied by interpretation serves to edify the entire church body.

> VERSE 22 Wherefore tongues are for a sign, not to them that believe, but to them that believe not: but prophesying serveth not for them that believe not, but for them which believe.

Tongues does not edify the church body, but it does serve as a sign to the unbeliever. 
Prophecy is not a sign to the unbeliever, but it does edify the assembled church body.

> VERSE 28 But if there be no interpreter, let him keep silence in the church; and let him speak to himself, and to God.

If there is no interpreter, then there is no means for the entire church body to be edified. Yet Scripture does not command that the man remain entirely silent; he is told only not to speak before the church a singular utterance in tongues.

This verse plainly states,

> **“. . . let him speak to himself, and to God.”**

He is to keep his utterance in tongues at a level which will not disrupt the flow of the service, yet continue to speak in tongues directly to God.

You will no doubt wonder why there are people who pray in tongues, and even sing in tongues in the assembled church, but no interpretation is ever given. The answer to this question is not as difficult as you might think.

Personal prayer and edification tongues are used to speak directly to God (1 Corinthians 14:2).

In a church assembly, where people are praising and worshiping God, praise and worship is always offered to God alone. Since tongues is used to speak directly to God, there is no need for an interpretation to be given for the use of tongues during praise and worship.

Likewise, when someone is praying in tongues during the church service, it is directed to God, and need not be interpreted. In both situations there are usually many people singing or praying at the same time, so that no one voice is distinguishable from another.

It must be understood that any utterance in tongues which is a singular utterance, obviously understood as being for or to the entire assembly, must always be accompanied by an interpretation so all may be edified.

Comment: Good answer! +1. A couple suggestions for improvement. 1) the phrases "baptism of the Holy Spirit" and "baptized in the Holy Spirit" are not strictly  biblical. True, the Spirit is "poured out," can be "received," and can "come upon" people, but people are not baptized INTO the Spirit; rather, they are baptized INTO THE NAME OF JESUS. 2) "praying in the Holy Ghost" (Jude) is not necessarily the same as praying in tongues, just as being filled with the Spirit isn't always accompanied by tongues. Being filled could be evidenced by the speaking of psalms, hymns, & spiritual songs to one another;

Comment: making melody to the Lord with one's heart; always being thankful for all things; and submitting to one another in the fear of Christ. (It almost goes without saying, the filling of the Spirit always comes with supernatural power and enabling in the use of our spiritual "gift mix" (C. Peter Wagner). 3) The Spirit's "intercession for us with groanings which cannot be uttered" is not necessarily speaking in tongues. By insisting it is, one is reading more into the text than is warranted. 4) Keeping one's "utterance from ...[disrupting] the flow of the service" is a good idea, but not biblical.

Comment: After considering your comment, I changed "of" and "in" to simply received the Holy Spirit baptism. I can live with that.

Comment: You might want to do that again, as your edits may have been erased between the time you made the edits and the time I finished my editing. Don

Comment: Interesting answer indeed, +1

Answer (score 2):

With two exceptions, the Greek words seen in Acts 2:4-11; 1 Cor. 14:2-20, and translated into English as "tongue" or "tongues," are forms of the Greek verb **ΓΛΩΣΣΑ** (*γλῶσσα*, glossa). The implication is that **glossa** refers to a regional dialect or language spoken by someone has not naturally learned it. *Glossa* does not refer to the ecstatic (enraptured) praise and worship or like utterances made by many modern Christians.

Comment: Do you mind pointing out where those two exceptions are, and what Greek word was used instead? Many thanks

Comment: @jirehpryor: Acts 2:6, 8 has fem. sing. dat. noun διαλεκτω for "language" in KJV).

Comment: @jirehpryor: cp. P74 01 02 03 04 05 08 044 18 33 81 323 424 614 945 1175 1241 1505 1739S

Answer (score 2):

## The Idea in Brief

The two types of tongues are (*a*) those that are understood, and (*b*) those that are not understood. When the tongue is understood, the unbeliever will receive the warning concerning the "great things of God," which include the message of forgiveness and impending judgment (Day of the Lord). If the hearer is the believer, the same message will be one of encouragement (edification). Finally, if the tongue remains untranslated, then its purpose then becomes for the exclusive use of the speaker, who may share the untranslated words with the Lord in personal private prayer.

## Discussion

The Spirit of God moves men in the way that the invisible wind exerts power ([Jn 3:8](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%203:8&version=NASB)); that is, the imagery is akin to how the wind propels the ship to move forward (meaning of verb [**φέρω**](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G5342&t=NASB) in [2 Pet 1:21](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Peter%201:21&version=NASB) referring to the Spirit of God). This nuance is why the verb "to prophesy" in Biblical Hebrew ([**נָבָא**](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H5012&t=NASB)), in addition to its triliteral cognates (*e.g*.,  [**נָבִיא**](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H5030&t=NASB) = "prophet"), are passive in construct but active in meaning. Thus "one is moved" by the Spirit of God "to prophesy," which includes *forth*-telling (singing, exhortation, teaching, correction) as well as *fore*-telling (predictive events about the future).  In one prophetic passage, the prophet Joel predicted the Day of the Lord, which would occur after the sign of prophesying among all men.

In the Hebrew Bible, the Prophet Joel predicted the outpouring of the Spirit of God, when all men, young and old, would prophesy and dream dreams ([Joel 2:28-32](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Joel%202%3A28-32&version=NASB), which Peter cited in [Acts 2:17-21](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%202:17-21&version=NASB)). This event would be the turning point (or sign to "the House of Israel" in [Acts 2:36](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%202%3A36&version=NASB)) that the Day of the Lord would follow, when anyone who calls upon the name of the Lord would be saved. The initial fulfillment of this prophecy therefore occurred at Pentecost according to Peter in the Book of Acts, when the New Covenant was announced to the House of Israel.

Pentecost thus is the "birthday" of the New Covenant to the House of Israel. The day is also the "birthday" of the Feast of Weeks (Shavuot), when the Old Covenant was given to the House of Israel at Sinai. That is, the festival for the outpouring of rain (50 days from festival of First Fruits) was the analog to the outpouring out of Spirit of God (50 days from "Christ our First Fruits"). Please click [**here**](https://sites.google.com/site/pent2828/home/PentecostENGLISH.jpg).

So in the Christian New Testament therefore, tongues became the sign to the House of Israel that the time of judgment was at hand (Day of the Lord), but through the New Covenant, repentance and the forgiveness of sins was now in order. So while tongues were the sign of warning to the unbeliever, the sign was also informative; that is, the tongues communicated information to the believer that, in turn, would have resulted in edification.

So in the Book of Acts, the Jewish proselytes in [Acts 2:8-11](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%202%3A8-11%20&version=NASB) had heard the "great things of God" spoken in their own language, which not only pointed to the Day of the Lord (judgment) but also to repentance declared in the New Covenant -- thus the sign was for warning. (In some cases, there is no phenomenon, such as was the case with Paul --then Saul-- who had received the outpouring of the Spirit of God through the laying of hands, but there was ***no*** result other than the shedding of scales from his eyes according to [Acts 9:17-18](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%209%3A17-18&version=NASB)). Finally, edification is the principal result for believers, as was the case when the Roman centurion Cornelius and his colleagues had received the same outpouring; the hearers present had understood them to have been "exalting God" ([Acts 10:46](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%2010%3A46&version=NASB)), which resulted in the glorification of God by Jewish believers who were joyful by the news of the spreading of the Gospel ([Acts 11:18](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%2011%3A18&version=NASB)). In this regard, the disciples of John the Baptist *both* spoke in tongues *and* prophesied in [Acts 19:1-6](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%2019%3A1-6&version=NASB). That is, prophesying suggests some kind of edification, which Paul had elaborated was the principal purpose of tongues for believers; by believers; and to believers.

In this regard, the Apostle Paul provides specific guidelines and nuance in [1 Cor 14:2-23](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Cor%2014:2-23&version=NASB) regarding the purpose of tongues for believers and unbelievers. That is, the sign (or spiritual gift) of tongues is either understood, or not understood by the hearer. Please see the following chart, *below*.

[image: Description of tongues]

## Conclusion

The two categories of tongues are (*a*) those that are understood (by translation, if needed), and (*b*) those that are not understood. If the hearers did not understand the tongue, and there was no translation available, then such tongues were to remain personal; that is, they were for the exclusive use of the speaker in private prayer with the Lord.

Comment: If the disciples "spoke in tongues" in Acts 2:4, and they were Galileans, how then would they have interpreted "what the Spirit gave them utterance"? Would they then have to wait for the appropriate linguist before they would 'give utterance' to what they knew not? Also, in Acts 10:46 they(Cornelius & household) spoke in tongues-who interpreted? It was said they "magnified God", but in what language?

Comment: No DV's for you, as you have taken the initiative to 'look at' rather than 'look against'. What I'm waiting to see here in these answers is CONTEXT: in other words, what CONTEXT is Paul speaking about when he gives his dictum concerning tongues? We certainly contextualize his argument about "a woman keeping silence, and all submission" as not meaning a woman may NEVER speak in church. Why don't we follow Paul's discussion about a Public Sunday Morning Worship Service, and not 'blanket it to mean 'in every circumstance'?(see 1 Cor. 1:23)

Comment: I meant 1 Cor. 14:23 :>}

Comment: @user2479 - I made several major edits in response to your comments. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

**A note on method:** We must always be careful not to pull a single verse from its context and develop doctrine based on it. To properly understand a text, one must first carefully read the entire text (i.e. book of Scripture), considering the occasion of the writing, and following the author's flow of thought. Only then can we discern the author's purpose in writing and ensure we do not abuse his words by making a single sentence out to teach something contrary to the author's intention.

**What is going on in Acts 2:** What we can glean from this text is that at Pentecost the Spirit supernaturally enabled communication to take place between people of different languages for the purpose of ministry. (The word "tongues" is used here, which just refers to languages, as Pat Ferguson noted.) We are not told whether the spiritual gift of "interpretation" was also in play.

**What is going on in 1 Cor 14:** As any good commentary will describe, the Corinthians were in bad shape. They were fleshly, prideful, spiritually immature,... the list goes on. Paul is addressing a slew of such problems in his letter, and urging them toward true spiritual maturity: loving their brothers. [See here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/5083/529) for a brief overview of the flow of thought through Chs. 12-14. The problem Paul is addressing in 1 Cor. 14 is chaos in the church service. The Corinthians were apparently showcasing their "superior spirituality" by uttering incomprehensible things in the middle of their church service. They seem to have been citing "personal edification" as their justification. Paul, as he does throughout the entire letter, addresses their selfishness and foolishness, and prescribes wise, loving behavior.

Verses 2-4 are part of his very patient and gentle explanation about why precisely it is ridiculous to publicly speak in incomprehensible languages. In light of the context of the book as a whole, and the immediate context, It is virtually inconceivable that Paul's intention in 14:2-4 was to detail a special new gift of "self-serving by the Spirit" - the Spirit who was specifically given for empowerment for ministry. (The Corinthians weren't even *trying* to minister to others!) Paul was trying to drive them in the direction of love (i.e. serving others in a self-sacrificial way) -- **not** in the direction of serving themselves. Paul's advice boils down to this: if you're going to manifest your spirituality by speaking in languages that no one understands, do it at home (unless someone can interpret it), because apart from God nobody can understand you! You're just making yourself look like a maniac, and you're not doing anything to edify the body.

**Conclusion:** In light of the occasion of the letter and the author's flow of thought throughout both the letter and the immediate context, it seems like a very bad idea to see in this verse a "teaching" on a special new gift of self-serving by the Spirit. It seems more appropriate to see this as part of a rebuke to a selfish and foolish congregation. As such, we should not draw any conclusions based on these verses that there is a special "second gift of tongues" being taught here. That may leave the reader wondering whether there *is* a second gift of tongues -- but that question would be better addressed on a theology site.

Comment: It's simply "ad hominem" to infer a particular behavioral pattern(and Paul's response to it) when Paul himself says," I thank my God, I speak with tongues more than ye all( 1 Cor. 14:18). If you're going to make a case against angelic tongues, make it, but don't make the text say what it doesn't say.

Comment: @user2479 I think you might be confusing Paul's appreciation for the spiritual gift of tongues with the Corinthians' self-centered abuse of that gift, which Paul pretty clearly was not OK with.

Comment: I don't read anywhere in the text that Paul said the use of tongues was "self-centered". I do read in the text where he proscribes their usage "decently, and in order". Oh, and by the way, women are told to keep silent in church, so apparently from 'proper exegesis' of this passage, only men spoke in tongues.......?

Comment: @user2479 If you would like me to help you understand my answer better (or the text) I would be happy to make time to do that for you. If you are just trolling and want to fight with me I won't waste any more time trying to explain.

Comment: My purpose is to expose your 'conjecturing' your own feelings concerning the text, and making Paul somehow 'agree' with them. If you are taking issue w/"tongues of angels", I would concede you have a point, and could bring evidence to uphold your convictions. This post doesn't do that, it simply 'denigrates' that practice and puts Paul 'somehow' in your camp.

Comment: BTW- I have upvoted many of your posts, as they are usually thoughtful, articulate, and knowledgeable. I believe in this case your 'prejudice' has obscured your ability to give an insightful argument.

Comment: @user2479 I haven't said anything about "tongues of angels", nor did the OP, nor does 1 Cor. 14. Nor have I said anything to "denigrate" the spiritual gift of tongues. Paul clearly believed in the gift of tongues, as do I. I am not a cessationist. It seems like you are upset about something that I said, but I'm not sure what exactly. TBH I'm a bit surprised by your reaction to my post, as I would have thought that everything I wrote would be fairly obvious in reading through 1 Cor (as most commentaries have noted.) You seem to either be trolling, misreading me, or biased against my conclusion.

Comment: @user2479 Like I said before, if you have any interest in understanding what I have written or how I (along with most commentators) perceive the problems in Corinth, I would be happy to take the time to explain further. But so far all you have given me is agitated ranting.

Comment: @user2479 I updated my post to clarify what I meant. Hope that helps.

Comment: The OP's question asked if "2 different types of tongues in the NT"; 1 of which are tongues of men, and 1 "mysteries of God", or tongues of angels per 1 Cor. 13:1. His question centers around these 2 entities, not whether or not the church at Corinth had issues which the Apostle Paul had to deal with. It is "ad hominem" to suggest that because the church in Corinth was immature, therefore their giftings are invalid. The 1st answer calls the 2 manifestations as 'different operations', and certainly an argument can be made for that.(cont.)

Comment: Another argument appears to be that there is no such thing as "tongues of angels", Paul is loosely interpreting "ecstatic speaking" of which no interpretation is needed or required, but it should not be manifested during a normal church service, especially when unbelievers are present. I don't particularly agree with that view but a legitimate argument can be made for such which I would certainly +1 for.

Comment: @user2479 This is not a theology site, and neither the OP nor the text in question mention this idea you're bringing to the text of "tongues of angels". That is eisogesis. I am arguing for respecting authorial intent and context.

Comment: The question succinctly said "TWO DIFFERENT TYPES OF TONGUES" so I'm not adding 'eisogesis'. If you don't want to refer to "speaking in mysteries"(1 Cor. 14:2) to "tongues of angels"(1 Cor. 13:1), that is your prerogative, but that is what the OP's question is about. It is clear we are NOT talking about prophecy. There are numerous sources to quote for "tongues of angels"; if one will accept 1 Cor. 13:1 as it is written, then one can acknowledge the existence of such-whether one agrees with it or not.

Comment: @user2479 The question was about the statement "no one understands" whereas in Acts two the gift of tongues was understood. It was not about "tongues of angels", which you appear to be ripping out of context from a separate passage than the one the OP asked about.

Comment: (sigh) Does the Heading of the Question Say, "Are There 2 Different Types of "Tongues" Spoken About in the NT?" Yes or No?

Comment: @user2479 Yes, but the OP's meaning was different than your interpretation of it. You are ripping the OP's question out of its context. The first sentence in the body of the question is "My question comes **directly** from 1 Cor 14: 2, 4", after which he goes on to explain his confusion over the discrepancy with Acts 2 pertaining to whether the tongues were understood (as I noted.) If the OP had meant what you thought he meant, the question would be off-topic for this site, because **this is not a theology site!**